# Add symbol to image url on hover with jquery

Tags: jquery, url, background-image

I was wondering if any of you could help me out a little?
So, I have 100 divs with different background images and I need to change these images on hover. The title of the new image is different with one letter, for example image.jpg and imageG.jpg

```
<div class="item first"></div>
<div class="item second"></div>
<div class="item third"></div>
<div class="item fourth"></div>
<div class="item fifth"></div>
```

etc..

I have in mind that it is probably possible with: making a variable which is the name of the image and than on hover adding that letter! I'm not really sure how to write this and would be really happy if some of you could help out!

Thank you in advance!

EDIT:

I came up with something like this, but it is not working. Do you have any idea how to improve?

```
$( ".item" ).hover(function() {
    var bg = $(this).css('background-image').split('/').pop().slice(0, -6);
    var newImg = bg + '.png';
    $('.item').css('background-image', newImg);
});
```

Comment: You could also do it with css and the :hover selector - search for "css background image hover" on this site.

Comment: I did that, but I figured jquery would be shorter. Anyway, thank you for your input.

Comment: If you use a sprite for your background images, it would be easy to just change the coordinates for the background image in the :hover state - e.g. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp

Comment: error in your current jQuery code: `$('.item')` refers to all `.item` divs; to set the bg image for the current div, you need to use `$(this).css(...)`

Comment: it is still not working.
I will answer this question when will figure out.

Comment: Can you put up a JSFiddle with links to your images?

Answer (score 0):

With Jquery may be you can try with this.

```
$("[class^='item ']").on('mouseenter mouseleave',function(e){
//change to alternate image

});
```

Comment: For that you need to first select all the `img` element. Second step is changing the img to alternate symbol or something.

Comment: Let her come back on this.

Comment: @TJ if you have better answer, post it.

Comment: Thank you all. I still haven't found the best way. But what if in the beginning we would do this: 

    <div class="item" id="first"></div>
    <div class="item" id="second"></div>
    <div class="item" id="third"></div>
    <div class="item" id="fourth"></div>

Background images are firstG.png, secongG.png etc. Than on hover we can set background image name as an id!

Comment: I came up with something like this, but it is not working. Do you have any idea how to improve?

    $( ".item" ).hover(function() {
     var bg = $(this).css('background-image').split('/').pop().slice(0, -6);
     var newImg = bg + '.png';
     $('.item').css('background-image', newImg);
    });

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS is more recommended than jQuery.

```
.item.first:hover{
 //new image background.
 }
```

Comment: And are you suggesting to write 100's of `:hover` classes for each image??

Comment: @TJ Only need one :hover class per image... :P

Comment: Yea... one per image, for 100's of them... :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something along these lines, it changes the last character prior to extension to uppercase on hover and reverses it on leave.

```
$(".item").hover(toggleImage);

function toggleImage() {
  var src = $(this).css("background-image").split("url(")[1];
  src = src.slice(0, src.length - 1);
  var len = src.length;
  var ext = src.substring(src.lastIndexOf("."), len);
  var name = src.substring(0, src.lastIndexOf("."));
  len = name.length;
  var letter = toggleCase(name.substring(len - 1, len));
  src = name.substring(0, len - 1) + letter + ext;
  $(this).css("background-image", "url('"+src+"')");
}

function toggleCase(char) {
  if (char.toUpperCase() != char) {
    return char.toUpperCase();
  }
  return char.toLowerCase();
}
```

for example, hover: `imageA.jpg`, leave: `imagea.jpg`

Comment: This is possibly the lenghiest way to achieve what the Op is looking for. Why re-inventing the wheel which we already have.?

Comment: @Java_User and which wheel that might be..?

Answer (score 0):

I would use an image sprite containing all your background images (that also means making a single HTTP request to get the image, rather than 100 separate requests to get all the individual images) and then use css to set the background position. It does mean writing out a fair bit of css, but that can be done programmatically by writing a quick script to generate the appropriate numbers. If you set out your sprite sensibly, the image background coordinates can be logical.

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pqw7u051/) example with an image sprite I found online.

Sample code:

```
.item {
    height: 38px;
    width: 100px;
    background-image: url('http://www.smashingmagazine.com/images/css-sprites/apple.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.d1 {
    background-position: 0 0
}
.d1:hover {
    background-position: 0 -38px;
}
.d2 {
    background-position: -118px 0;
}
.d2:hover {
    background-position: -118px -38px;
}
.d3 {
    background-position: -234px 0;
}
.d3:hover {
    background-position: -234px -38px;
}
```

If you don't want to write out all those hover classes, you could do the same thing using jQuery to calculate the new background position:

```
$( ".item" ).on('mouseenter mouseleave',function(e){
    var bg = $(this).css('background-position').split(' ');
    // bg[0] = x position, bg[1] = y position
    if (bg[1] === '0px') {
        $(this).css('background-position', bg[0] + ' -38px');
    } else {
        $(this).css('background-position', bg[0] + ' 0px');
    }
});
```

[jQuery hovering](http://jsfiddle.net/pqw7u051/1/)